# How to place an iframe over an image?

Tags: html, iframe

I'd like to place an image under my iframe, but i've pieced together some code and it doesn't appear to be exactly right.  The iframe contains text and has a transparent background.  Can you help me out?  thanks,

```
<td width="216" style="position: relative;">
<img src="http://southwestarkansasradio.com/images/onair995.jpg"></a><br>
<img src="http://southwestarkansasradio.com/images/playerbackground.jpg" style="z-index:  -1"/>
<div style="absolute;left:0px;top:0px;font-size: 32px;display: none">
  <iframe name="I1" width="316" height="216" src="http://southwestarkansasradio.com /NowPlaying.html" border="0" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true">
Your browser does not support inline frames.</iframe>

</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<img src="http://southwestarkansasradio.com/images/onair995.jpg"></a><br>
<img src="http://southwestarkansasradio.com/images/playerbackground.jpg" style="z-index:  -1"/>
<div style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;font-size: 32px">
  <iframe width="316" height="216" src="http://southwestarkansasradio.com/NowPlaying.html" border="0" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true">
      Your browser does not support inline frames.</iframe>
</div>
```

You have 'display:none' on the div tag that contains the iframe. I tested the above code and it works as you have explained is should.

Comment: And if you would like to move the iframe down a bit to fit over the image rather than the banner as well, just add `margin-top:40px;` or however many pixels the picture is to move the iframe down.  Add this to the style attribute on the div tag that contains the iframe.

Comment: thanks, i think the problem was also the missing "position:"...now to align it.